# Renaming packages in a common library without breaking downstreams

Tags: java, dependencies, package

We have a common library of classes that have poor package naming. I want to change the package names in the common library.

However, I don't want to suddenly break all downstreams depending on this library when I merge the change.

Can I...

1. use some kind of symlinks to point the new package structure to another?
2. add two packages to the same class?
3. otherwise create a "pointer" from one package to another?

My best "brain-dead" solution so far is to literally copy all the library classes and paste them into a new directory structure and rename those classes. Thus there will be "parallel" classes in both packages. (Which will almost certainly lead to divergence :( )

Comment: Thats' why we have different versions. Use 2 versions and you can use different versions in downstream services and hence problem solved

Comment: @Naruto We don't currently have an internal mvn repository to store multiple versions of the library, which I think we'd need to be able to do that. The common library is referenced in the pom and we have to build it separately. It's in the same git repo, so branching probably won't help either.

Comment: Different versions is what we ended up doing. They had to be built when the dependent project switched over, but local repos did the work.